# How to add the CSS styling to this piece of code within my program

Tags: php, html, css, eclipse

So this is my code that I am trying to add the CSS Styling to its contained within a HereDoc

```
<div class = "row>
    <div class="column">
        <div style="WebAppS15/css/TeamManagment.css;">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Squad Role</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jurgen</td>
                    <td>Klopp</td>
                    <td>Manager</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zelko</td>
                    <td>Buljvak</td>
                    <td>Assistant Manager</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gary</td>
                    <td>McAllister</td>
                    <td>Head Coach</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Krawietz</td>
                    <td>Assistant Coach</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tom</td>
                    <td>Werner</td>
                    <td>Chairman</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I do not think I have the location wrong but I am not seeing any change whenever I adjust the pixel width in the TeamManagment css file on this file that I am attempting to link it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how it works. You need to include the css file with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="WebAppS15/css/TeamManagment.css">
```

And set a class to the div like this:

```
<div class="class-name">
```

So, in your WebAppS15/css/TeamManagment.css file, you set the custom css for that class with:

```
.class-name {
  // Properties
}
```

Another option is to configure the CSS inside the html file like this:

```
<style>

.class-name {
  // Properties
}

</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="class-name">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Squad Role</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Jurgen</td>
           <td>Klopp</td>
           <td>Manager</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Zelko</td>
           <td>Buljvak</td>
           <td>Assistant Manager</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Gary</td>
           <td>McAllister</td>
           <td>Head Coach</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Peter</td>
           <td>Krawietz</td>
           <td>Assistant Coach</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Tom</td>
           <td>Werner</td>
           <td>Chairman</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The Program is in PHP not HTML so how would I call the css file into the program in this case?